# WebRTC ~ Possible to connect when knowing IP and PORT without using Intermediate Servers

Tags: javascript, p2p, webrtc

I know there is lot's of documentation about WebRTC out there so I am sorry if I missed it:

My question is the following:

Is it possible to connect from client to client without using an intermediate server. ( Including an intermediate server to set up the connection )

Take as example two clients that know each other IP addresses and the ports they are using for RTC. Both did they already downloaded the webpage. Is it possible for them to connect without an intermediate signal server?

I hope you would point me to a good source of how this is possible! Or why not!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not as easy as that to set up the connection. There is more information that needs to be  provided than ip and port. There are 'offer', 'answer' and 'candidates' that are sent between the peers.

These are readable text and the could very well be typed in by the user but since they are quite large, it is more easy to provide them via the server in the middle.

You could mail them and type them in at the remote peer...

Comment: Thanks for the response at first! After researching long I figured out a bit more about WebRTC and Ice! There's just one thing I am still really wondering about. When the remote and local descriptions are set at both sides the RTCPeerConnection automatically sends the stream? Is it possible to set the IceCandindates directly in de SDP and add that as a Description ( local and remote? )

Thanks for the help again!

Comment: As I recall it, SDP supports this functionality and I do not see why you shouldn't be able to send the candidates in the SDP in your webRTC implementation. But the WebRTC API have one function for setting the remote description (setRemoteDescription) and another for adding candidates (addIceCandidate) so I believe you would have to handle them separately in the receiving end anyway.

Comment: As a last question! ( Thanks for your help! ) Do you have any link or documentation/source on how to create a serverless WebRTC?

Comment: No, simply because there is no serverless solution that could work satisfactorily in a real life implementation. (At least to my understanding...)

Comment: Mmm Okay thanks! I'll accept this one:P Even though I am still continueing to search for one that isn't a real life implementation!

Comment: You will probably find several examples without servers. But all these only uses a single computer and creates both "peers" in the same browser same session and just passes candidates etc. as function calls.

Comment: Mmm Any idea if there's a place I can gain more insight on how the communication establishes? Thanks a lot already! If I could vote up twice I would:P